# How big were the proton bombs in The Empire Strikes Back?

Tags: star-wars, weapon

The Imperial forces used proton bombs in an attempt to root out the *Millenium Falcon* in the Anoat asteroid fields in *The Empire Strikes Back.* How big were they?

Comment: I don't know for sure but based on certain online documentation I can assume they spanned about 1 meter across. The reason I'm commenting it here is because I dont remember for certain and would need to look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About two meters long

From *Star Wars: Rebels*, we now have a plethora of images showing proton bombs relative to other objects whose scale is quite well-known. Here they are in “The Last Battle,” relative to the familiar B-1 battle droids.

[image]

[According to the Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/battle-droid), these droids are about 2 meters in height. The proton bombs appear to be roughly as tall as the droids, so they are probably also around 2 meters.

Answer (score 1):

I just watched the entire asteroid scene in the film and at no time does it mention the type of bombs used, let alone their strength. You can see the Millenium Falcon being fired upon, but it does not verbally provide any information about proton bombs.Perhaps the information is given in the books. As I am unfamiliar with those, I cannot say.